# ssh: connecting through localhost port 22

Tags: linux, ssh

Hey so whenever I try connecting ssh through port 22 I get this error,

ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

The linux computers have a static IP of 192.168.2.128/129

I reinstalled ssh fresh and still get this error, I've been able to get 
access to my device but without privileges
Can someone help or guide me in sucessfully connecting both linux terminals,
any help is appreciated. Thx

When i ssh -v pwnie@localhost 192.168.2.128 from my laptop I get a permissions token error

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-6, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

> `ssh -v pwnie@localhost 192.168.2.128`

This command would try to connect to your laptop if you run it on your laptop. `localhost` is always the machine you look this up on itself, so on your laptop, `localhost` is your laptop...

If you want to connect as user `pwnie` to `192.168.2.128` run `ssh pwnie@192.168.2.128`.

And learn the fundamentals before running any kind of servers on the internet.